Show google photos in google maps TIMELINE
My google photos no longer appear since TIMELINE switched to smartphone and is no longer available on the web.
The "Google Photos" setting is ON.
My photos are all geolocated and appear well in GOOGLE PHOTOS

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
